# Can You Send Oauth Users Private Confirmation Messages?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, linkedin-api

I am using facebook, linkedin and twitter oauth services to create a user account on my app.  I am wondering if it is possible to send any sort of confirmation or follow up message to these new users via my application.

All I can seem to find is message services direct from user to user.

Comment: You could try Business on Messenger for talking to Facebook users as a business/app (https://www.messenger.com/business)